# Equation of a parabola in 3D space

Tags: conic-sections, 3d, parametric

I have two points with coordinates A(x1,y1,z1) and B(x2,y2,z2). There is a third point which is vertex(lowest point) of the parabola. I only know z-coordinate of this point. I need to find coordinates of the points that lie on a parabola that passes through these 3 points. I am interested in coordinates that lie in between A and B.

Comment: Seems to me that this is not enough information to find the equation of this parabola.

Comment: A and B are top coordinates of the vertical lines. That is A is top coordinate of a vertical line and similarly B is a top coordinate of another vertical line. Vertical here means a line parallel to z axis i.e. going through xy plane. So basically my plane in which parabola lies, is fixed, which is a plane passing through these lines. I know the equation of the plane in which parabola lies,two points on parabola, and z coordinate of the vertex. Can i find equation(i think parametric equation is easier since i am interested in finding points between A and B that lie on this parabola)?

Comment: If A and B share the same height, then it could be doable, though at this point I wouldn't know. Certainly the equation would have to be in parametric form as it is a curve in space

Comment: A and B do not have same height...That is their z coordinates are different.

Comment: When all three points in space are known, then I know a method to find parametrics for a parabola that passes through them, otherwise I think you are short of information.

Comment: ok...can you tell me how to do that when you know all three points?Also i was just thinking cant we use the fact that third point is a vertex(the lowest point) of the parabola and therefore axis of symmetry passes through it and is parallel to z axis?

Answer (score 3):

According to your comment added later the parabola lies in a vertical plane through the two points $A=(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ and $B=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and has a vertical axis. It therefore has a parametric representation of the form
$$s\mapsto\left\{\eqalign{x(s)&=(1-s)x_0+sx_1 \cr y(s)&=(1-s)y_0+sy_1 \cr z(s)&=as^2+bs+c\cr}\right.$$
It remains to determine the three coefficients $a$, $b$, $c$ from the data. We want $z(0)=z_0$ and $z(1)=z_1$. The third equation comes from the fact that we are also given the minimal value $z_*$ of $s\mapsto z(s)=as^2+bs+c$. This leads to the equation
$$-{b^2\over 4a}+c=z_*\ ,$$
so that we can now determine $a$, $b$, $c$ in a straightforward way.